# why jython can't load the jieba module

Tags: nlp, jython-2.7

I want use nlp lib(jieba 0.3.8) to cut my sentences. I can run it in python 2.7,but can't import in jython 2.7.

**The error info is below:**

> import jieba
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/mengbin/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/jieba/**init**.py", line 15, in 
>       from ._compat import *
>   ImportError: No module named _compat

if any one solve this problem, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

mengbin